# Jetty Rewrite NoSuchMethodException

Tags: mod-rewrite, jetty

I tried to configure jetty rewrite rules. I used code from the example here: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-handlers.html#d0e10798
but when I try to run it I get:

```
2013-09-29 18:05:48.256:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Set name="replacement">/redirected</Set> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule.setReplacement(class java.lang.String) in file:/opt/jetty/etc/jetty-rewrite.xml

2013-09-29 18:05:48.261:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Call name="addRule">|<Arg>|<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule">|<Set name="pattern">/redirect/*</Set>|<Set name="replacement">/redirected</Set>|</New>|</Arg>|</Call> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: class org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule.setReplacement(class java.lang.String) in file:/opt/jetty/etc/jetty-rewrite.xml
2013-09-29 18:05:48.262:WARN:oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">|<Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>|<Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>|<Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>|                        ||<Call name="addRule">|<Arg>|<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule">|<Set name="pattern">/redirect/*</Set>|<Set name="replacement">/redirected</Set>|</New>|</Arg>|</Call>|                                                                        ||<Call name="addRule">|<Arg>|<New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">|<Set name="pattern">/some/old/context</Set>|<Set name="replacement">/some/new/context</Set>|</New>|                                                                  </Arg>|                                                                        </Call>|                                                                          |      |      <Call name="addRule">|              <Arg>|                        <New
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set name="replacement"
```

to

```
Set name="location"
```

while configuring `RedirectPatternRule` in `jetty-rewrite.xml`, [as it is in the old jetty website](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Rewrite_Handler#PatternRule).

For me it worked(Jetty 9.1.0).